# Can I use a GFCI receptacle to feed a hardwired fountain pump?

Tags: electrical, wiring, pump, fountain

Question about a fountain pump…
The fountain pump will be hardwired.
Is it okay by code to feed a GFCI receptacle (line side) from the circuit breaker and then wire load side to the pump.
Will this suffice for GFCI protection?

Comment: How many HP is the fountain pump, and what other loads are on the circuit?

Comment: My apologies, I will find out the HP of the pump motor. I do know it will be on a dedicated circuit.

Answer (score 2):

That's a fine way to do that, *provided* Code allows a receptacle on the fountain circuit.

(In some cases it does not; for instance a dishwasher circuit is not allowed to have receptacles in a kitchen, and any circuit with hardwired loads > 50% of circuit ampacity is not allowed to have any sockets at all.)

If you are not allowed to have sockets on the circuit, then you can use a GFCI breaker or a standalone GFCI (called a GFCI Deadfront or blankface). They also make GFCI switches, which are a deadfront rated for daily switching duty.

Comment: My last two dishwashers were installed with a receptacle for the dishwasher to plug into.  They were not hard-wired.

Comment: Thank you for this knowledge and information. I did not even think of a blank face GFCI as an option. That may work perfectly. 
Thank you for your response.

Comment: @steveSh and dishwashers often require a disconnect switch in the kitchen, which gets really confusing as now there's this switch next to the disposal switch that you never should throw. Well, a switch-rated GFCI deadfront solves that nicely, by presenting a really weird user interface that no one will mistake for a normal switch.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes.

What size pump motor what size circuit? 15 or 20 amp.
Will be needed to properly answer but a sure fire way to get a yes answer is to install a “dead face GFCI”.

What is a dead face GFCI? It is a device that has no receptacle just the test and reset buttons.

I use these in locations where I want GFCI protection locally but do not want receptacles like on the surround of a jetted tub or when I want a under/ inside cabinet receptacle to have an easy access reset on the face of the cabinet (higher end homes usually).

There are ways to do it but depending on the answer to the pump size and circuit size a dead face may required.

Comment: Ed, thanks a great deal for your time and response. I have never thought before of the concept/use of the dead face GFCI. I will have to check the size of the pump anyhow. I know it is 120vac. And the electrician ran a 12 gauge so it will most likely be a 20 amp circuit (not a long run from panel). I will confirm the nameplate. I just want to make sure I am up to code. Thank you. 
Now I need to confirm the  possible need for a disconnect or more specifically accessibility requirements. 
Perhaps that is for another thread. 
Thank you very much